# Switching between a python 2.7 Jupyter Notebook and python 3.5 Jupyter Notebook

Tags: macos, ubuntu, python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Due to some of the work I do and classes I am in I frequently find my self needing to use both python 2 and python 3 jupyter notebooks. I installed both notebook servers using pip (pip3 for python 3 notebook server) but I am looking for a way to easily run both (preferably at the same time, but switching between them easily would also be great) without changing system wide settings for which version of python I am using, because it often causes confusion when running python code that is in the wrong version.

tl;dr: How Can I easily switch between running a python 2.7 jupyter notebook server and a python 3.5 notebook server?

(Note I use OS X and Ubuntu but getting this working on OS X is a priority over Ubuntu)

Comment: Seems like a duplicate question of [this on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492623/using-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-ipython-notebook) Refer to that question's answer.